# Testing DB Link - ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, toad, dblink

I know there is a load of times this question has been asked but I can't quite figure out how to apply this information to my situation.

I have two databases of which I'm trying to connect with a DB LINK.  These are:

- BBEGMTD1
- OPEGMTP1.WORLD

A DB link has already been defined by someone, with the name PE_DBLINK.WORLD.

I can access **both** of these databases from my machine, so I can't see how tnsnames.ora would be affected.

However when I test the DB LINK I get the famous:

> Link  : "PE_DBLINK.WORLD" Error : ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the
>   connect identifier specified

Could you please point me in the right direction, does the tnsnames.ora need to be modified on the BBEGMTD1 server?

As per @Chance comment, `select * from ALL_DB_LINKS` returns:

```
PUBLIC                        
PE_DBLINK.WORLD                                                                 
PRICING                       
OPEGMTP1.WORLD                                                                  
03-NOV-11

PUBLIC                        
EBPROJ.WORLD                                                                    
EBPROJ                        
MIDGMTP1                                                                        
17-JUN-09

MYOPEGMTP1WORLD.WORLD                                                           
PRICING                       
(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=ORA04SOUK) (PORT=1521) ) (CONNECT_D
ATA= (SERVER=dedicated) (SERVICE_NAME=OPEGMTT1) ) ) )                           
16-DEC-11
```

This is the TNSNames Editor in TOAD to show the details are being shown up:

[image]

Comment: run this and post the result here:`select * from   ALL_DB_LINKS`

Comment: Post what see from TOAD the contenet of tnsnames.ora. And post the content of the table ALL_DB_LINKS again.

Comment: I've added the TNS Viewer however I'm having trouble executing your create link command (not correctly ended) although I did create a link through the GUI to no avail

Comment: Can you show me the content of table ALL_DB_LINKS again?

Answer (score 5):

1. Run this to check the host of the DBLink PE_DBLINK.WORLD:

   select * from   ALL_DB_LINKS
2. Check your tnsnames.ora fro the HOST (i.e. OPEGMTP1.WORLD ) of that DBLink. Which is located at (your locale machine)

   %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
3. If not found in your tnsnames.ora, then add it like this:

   OPEGMTP1.WORLD = (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=ORA04SOUK) (PORT=1521) ) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVER=dedicated) (SERVICE_NAME=OPEGMTT1) ) )
4. Or create your own DBLink:

   CREATE DATABASE LINK MYOPEGMTP1.WORLD 
   CONNECT TO user IDENTIFIED BY password
   USING '(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=ORA04SOUK) (PORT=1521) ) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVER=dedicated) (SERVICE_NAME=OPEGMTT1) ) ) )'

Comment: It's not there, although I did add: `PE_DBLINK.WORLD=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=ORA04SOUK)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME=OPEGMTT1)
    )
  )` to tnsames.ora to no avail

Comment: Also there are no entries with `HOST=OPEGMTP1.WORLD` is that what I'm missing?

Comment: I think so. Or you can alter that DBLink.

Comment: Cheers for that - I've still got the same problem after closing + opening TOAD

Comment: Are are sure you have editted the right tnsnames.ora correctly?

Comment: When I connect to the database I'm using a connection who's `ORACLE_HOME` is `C:\app\medmondson\product\11.2.0\client_3\ ` and the file I'm editing is `C:\app\medmondson\product\11.2.0\client_3\network\admin\tnsnames.ora`.  I've added your entry but it's still the same.  Although to edit the file I have to copy it away and back again (another process is using it).

Comment: View the tnsnames.ora from TOAD to see if you have changed the right one. Or try to create your own DBLINK from BBEGMTD1.

Comment: Tried both - TOAD certainly sees the correct file, and creating a new link generates the exact same message `Link  : "link"
Error : ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified!`

Comment: Option 4 is the one that works for me. Best one because it doesn't use tnsname.ora file...

Answer (score 4):

It worked fine for me without any additional changes to tnsnames.ora file:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK <link> CONNECT TO <user> IDENTIFIED BY <password> USING
'(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <host>)(PORT = <port>))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = <service_name>)
    )
)';
```

Answer (score 2):

Check on the source DB host for valid TNS entries.  The DB Link is created from RDBMS Host to RDBMS Host, your PC is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a private DB link, you need to login as the DB Link Owner to test.

Answer (score 0):

If you face any issue related to ORA-12514.

Scenario: customer is trying to connect to server A from server B using DB link then he gets ORA-12514 error.  if the server A doesn’t not have the SID_LIST_LISTENER entry in the listener of server A ( this generally happens after upgrade) then he might get the error.

Error Code : ORA-12514: TNS: listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Resolution : Add the SID_LIST_LISTENER entry in target Listener ( of server A)

Note # most of you must be aware.

Answer (score -1):

db_link are from db server to db server, not from client to server; so please make sure your both database servers have correct tns entries for service.

tnsnames.ora on Database server should have tns entries for service.